# Select a Dropdown using Capybara ElementNotFound

Tags: css, ruby, automation, capybara, materialize

I'm trying to select an item from a dropdown with Capybara. I have done this just fine using a different CSS framework; now I'm using Materialize.

I have talked with the developer and he mentioned that Materialize uses two select boxes and so it might be getting confused there. Not sure if that's helpful but I thought I'd mention it.

I'm dealing with CSS that looks something like

```
  <div class="select-wrapper country required">
    <span class="caret">▼</span>    
    <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-0e5c0ffe-1e78-5df0-c08d-7bced194abd1" value="">    

    <ul id="select-options-0e5c0ffe-1e78-5df0-c08d-7bced194abd1" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 435px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;"><li class="">  <span></span></li>
        <li class=""><span>Afghanistan</span></li>
        <li class=""><span>Åland Islands</span></li>
        <li class=""><span>Albania</span></li>
        <li class=""><span>Algeria</span></li>
        <li class=""><span>United States</span></li></ul>       

    <select class="country required initialized"   name="store[address_attributes][country]" id="store_address_attributes_country"><option value=""></option>
        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
        <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
```

What I've tried is

```
select "United States", :from => 'store_address_attributes_country'
```

I've also tried

```
find("store_address_attributes_country").select("United States")
```

(I also tried this same thing using the XPath, selector and name instead of the ID)

These give me the error

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find select box "store_address_attributes_country`
```

Comment: Are you sure `#store_address_attributes_country` didn't work?

Comment: have you tried save_and_open_page and checked if the element is really rendered?

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll Yes I am sure that didn't work for me either.

Comment: @pascalbetz I have and I can confirm it is visible. It's below the scope of the page but it finds the button out of the scope of the page as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using materialize the <select> element is hidden on the page and replaced with an <input> element as the trigger and  <ul> and <li> elements as the dropdown.  Because of this you can't use `#select`.  Instead you have to replicate what a user would have to do, which is click on the input used to trigger the dropdown and then click on the correct li.  In this case that would be

```
find("input.select-dropdown").click
find("li", text: "United States").click
```

Obviously the first find would have to be scoped to something on the page (or increase the specificity of the selector) if there is more than one select on the page

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Worked perfectly, thank you so much.